# Is ordering by rowid in SQLite guaranteed to be fast

Tags: database, sqlite, optimization

I have a simple SQLite database on which I am performing a bulk, performance-sensitive read. Its schema looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE test (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, idB INTEGER, category INTEGER);
```

I insert elements from each category in order of increasing idB, so a sequence of `(idB, category)` inserts might look like this:

```
(0, 0)
(1, 0)
(2, 0)
(3, 0)
(0, 1)
(1, 1)
(2, 1)
(0, 2)
(1, 2)
(2, 2)
(3, 2)
...
```

I have put indices on both the idB and the category columns. I have found that this query:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE category = 1 ORDER BY idB ASC;
```

is somewhat slower than this query

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE category = 1 ORDER BY rowid ASC;
```

Which I assume is because SQLite knows that the DB is stored in order of increasing rowid, but doesn't know that it also happens to be stored in order of increasing id. That's fine for my application, but I'm wondering **is this ordering by rowid guaranteed to be faster than other indexed columns**? That is, will SQLite consistently choose to store its DB by ordered rowid, such that ordering by rowID will always be fast?

Comment: When in doubt, `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN <your query here>` can give you a rough guideline.

Comment: Yes in this case it made it clear why it was faster to sort with `rowid`, since when sorting with the other id it had a second explicit sort on index phase, which it didn't in the `rowid` case. I was wondering whether that was guaranteed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing is ever *guaranteed*.

However, the [documentation states](http://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) that sorting will be faster (my emphasis):

> The data for rowid tables is stored as a B-Tree structure containing one entry for each table row, using the rowid value as the key. **This means that retrieving or sorting records by rowid is fast**. Searching for a record with a specific rowid, or for all records with rowids within a specified range is around twice as fast as a similar search made by specifying any other PRIMARY KEY or indexed value.

and that rows are [stored as you state](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html):

> The rows are logically stored in order of increasing rowid.